# Partial twocolumn itemize

Tags: lists, two-column, itemize

Sometimes itemize/enumerate environments have some items who are quite short and some items who are longer.

I wish to format such environments into a compact way. For example turning:

```
* A
* B
* C
* DDDDDDDDDDDDD
* EEEEEEEEE
```

into:

```
* A     * B
* C
* DDDDDDDDDDDDD
* EEEEEEEEE
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: My impression is that your readers will be quite confused by this layout.

Comment: Sometimes indeed, one should use it with care. However I was wondering if it is technically (easily) possible. An author can still decide after the result is compiled.

Comment: Have a look at `tablists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-off, you can make your own `\fakeitem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newcommand{\fakeitem}{%
  \hspace*{\itemindent}%
  \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\textbullet}%
  \hspace*{\labelsep}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \fakeitem B
  \item C
  \item DDDDDDDDDDD
  \item EEEEEEEE
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Of course, it really depends on your actual usage how effective this might be.